# docker secrets for configuration files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-registry

It is more like design pattern question for docker secrets. We have bunch of configuration properties files and almost none of them has any secret properties like user id, pass word. Should I use docker secrets to inject though configuration files into container ? Or is there any other design pattern that can be better to injects those configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 17.06 you can use docker configs for that (If you use swarm mode). Configs are like docker secrets but not encrypted. https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/configs/